# How to calculate differences between the coefficients (categorical variables) of glm procedure in Rstan

Tags: r, comparison, glm, bayesian, rstan

I have a question about the how to calculate differences between the coefficients (categorical variables) of glm in Rstan.

As example, I used iris dataset in R to judge whether I can calculate the posterior distribution of differences of coefficients.

At first, I conducted a basic glm procedure like below and calculate the significant differences of coefficients.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(multcomp)

iris_glm <-
glm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) 

multcomp::glht(iris_glm, linfct = mcp(Species = "Tukey")) %>% 
summary(.) %>% 
broom::tidy() 

                     lhs rhs estimate std.error statistic      p.value
1    versicolor - setosa   0    0.930 0.1029579  9.032819 0.000000e+00
2     virginica - setosa   0    1.582 0.1029579 15.365506 0.000000e+00
3 virginica - versicolor   0    0.652 0.1029579  6.332686 4.294805e-10
```

Next, I conducted bayesian glm procedure using stan like below code, and calculate the posterior distribution of the differences between coefficients in generated quantities section.

```
# Make the model matrix for Rstan
iris_mod <-
model.matrix(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) %>%
as.data.frame(.)

# Input data
stan_data <-
list(N = nrow(iris_mod),
SL = iris$Sepal.Length,
Intercept = iris_mod$`(Intercept)`,
versicolor = iris_mod$Speciesversicolor,
virginica = iris_mod$Speciesvirginica)

# Stan code

data{
int N;
real <lower = 0> SL[N];
int <lower = 1> Intercept[N];
int <lower = 0, upper = 1> versicolor[N];
int <lower = 0, upper = 1> virginica[N];
}

parameters{
real beta0;
real beta1;
real beta2;
real <lower = 0> sigma;
}

transformed parameters{
real mu[N];
for(n in 1:N) mu[n] = beta0*Intercept[n] + beta1*versicolor[n] +       
beta2*virginica[n];
}

model{
for(n in 1:N) SL[n] ~ normal(mu[n], sigma);
}

generated quantities{
real diff_beta0_beta1;
real diff_beta1_beta2;
real diff_beta0_beta2;

diff_beta0_beta1 = (beta0 + beta1) - beta0;
diff_beta1_beta2 = (beta0 + beta1) - (beta0 + beta2);
diff_beta0_beta2 = (beta0 + beta2) - beta0;
}


library(rstan)
fit_stan <- 
stan(file = "iris.stan", data = stan_data, chains = 4, 
seed = 1234)

# confirmation of posterior distribution
print(fit_stan, pars = c("diff_beta0_beta1", "diff_beta1_beta2", 
"diff_beta0_beta2"))

                  mean se_mean  sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
diff_beta0_beta1 0.92       0 0.1 0.73 0.86 0.92 0.99  1.13  2041    1
diff_beta1_beta2 0.65       0 0.1 0.45 0.58 0.65 0.72  0.86  4000    1
diff_beta0_beta2 1.58       0 0.1 1.38 1.51 1.58 1.64  1.78  1851    1
```

Finally, I could get same results between the frequentist method and bayesian method.
I think this is correct way, but I'm not sure this because there are no information nor examples.
Also I also confirm this way could be extended another error distributions (including, poisson, gamma, binomial, negative- binomial etc.).

If there are another good ways or advices, please teach me.

Comment: Everything works the same way no matter what the link function (e.g., log) and likelihood are (e.g., Poisson).  You're better off not multiplying by intercept but just adding the `Intercept[n]` term.  If you do want to do it this way, you could drop all of beta into a vector adn just use vector multiplication.  Vectorizing the likelihood to `SL ~ normal(mu, sigma)` will be much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for replying my questions. The advice of vectorization is useful to make models.

Comment: And I want to reconfirm the generated quantities section. Do you think this is correct way ? If so, I can use this in another error distribution based on your advice. That will be great help for me.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do here.  When you have `(beta0 + beta1) - beta0`, that's just going to evaluate to `beta1`, since the `beta0` cancel out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate any function (including the difference in coefficients) of draws (such as those produced by Stan) from any proper posterior distribution.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, you can us the generated quantities block to define transforms of the data and parameters which then get handled like any other random variables if they involve parameters.  So any function you calculuate of parameters, you will get posterior means and posterior quantiles (medians and intervals).